# How to tell rev # and diff a prior version w/ previous version using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, repository, tortoisesvn, svn-repository

Using TortoiseSVN, I checked out a branch (HEAD) and then changed the local copy's revision to an older revision with `Update to revision...`.

For example, say the HEAD is rev.20. I updated to rev.10.

1. How can I tell what is the rev number of the current local copy? When opening the log or the revision graph, I get all the revisions up to the HEAD (1 to 20), w/o an indication for the checked out one (10).
2. Trying to `Diff with previous version` I get a diff of the local copy of the file (10) w/ the HEAD-1 (19) revision, which is actually a later revision than the local one. How do I diff with the previous-to-local (9) revision file?

---

**Update 1:** It appears that `Show log` shows the line of the current revision in boldface font, so this indicates what revision is currently updated to the local copy. Similarly, `revision graph` emphasizes the revision rectangle.

**Update 2:** I must have done something wrong before posting the question. It looks like now the `Diff with previous version` works as expected.

Comment: How about making these an answer?

Comment: @Ben - usually, a good idea. In this case, the grounds for the question seems to be not well established, so I felt and update is better. I have no objection for the question to be closed.